# Finding location of roots of polynomial using Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

The question I need to solve using the Argument Principle is:

In which quadrants do the roots of the polynomial $P(z)=z^4+z^3+4z^2+2z+3$ lie?

I think I first need to show that no zeros are on the real or imaginary axes but am not sure how to show it (apparently it's meant to be fairly simple to do).

Then I need to use the argument principle but I really struggle with this kind of problem. If you have the time I'd really appreciate an in-depth explanation of how to do this problem. Many thanks in advance to anyone who is able to help me!

Comment: Showing that $P$ has no zeros 'on the axes'  is equivalent to showing that $P(bi) \neq 0$ for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $P(a)\neq 0$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: One can show by the argument principle that the roots lie in quadrants 2 and 3. I dont know how to prove the roots are not real. I think the question is not asking this.